# Set multiple value using @IBDesignable

Tags: swift3, swift4

How do I create @IBDesignable for set deferent value when I run app on iPhone and ipad

Comment: @IBDesignable is not for set different values, rather it is used for direct rendering of a UIView or NSView in Interface builder. Your question shows nothing of your effort. first research about that attribute. [check this](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/). try to implement, if stuck anywhere, post your problem with some code that you have done so far

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Sounds like you need to use IBInspectable instead. Anyway, try to show some code, some tries, something you have tried, more than "please do it for me"